# Spring boot mongodb autoconfigure throws exception "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE"

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring boot to develop a Spring batch application. I will need my application to write the data finally to MongoDB and thus needs to configure `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate` for `org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemWriter`.

My **pom.xml** dependency section looks like this-

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jongo/jongo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>1.50.5</version>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>RELEASE</version>-->
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

The **application.properties** file looks like this

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongohost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=authdb
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=pwd

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=<< I don't know what to put here >>
```

**Main** class is also simple enough and looks like this-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I try to run my **Main** class it gives out error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

After researching a lot about this problem, I figured out that I need to let Spring know about my data store by providing the value of *spring.datasource.driver-class-name* in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mongodb.Server
```

If I provide `com.mongodb.Server` as my drive class name its not found on classpath and isn't recognised despite I have mongo java driver dependency on my classpath.

What should I put the value for mongoDB's driver-class-name provided I want to use `mongo-java-driver`?

If driver class name is not the cause of this issue, what should be the resolution of issue `"Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE"`mentioned in title of this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try exluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` in your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also you don't need this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name
```

unless you need jpa configuration as well.